# Password combinatorics on identical notes

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorics-on-words

I have the following two questions:

> A password consists only small letters a,…,z
>
> 1. How many possibilities are there to put in a hat two identical folded notes such that on
>      one of them is a password of length 6 and on the other a password of length 7, such
>      that no letter repeats twice (not on the same note, and not between the two notes)? Is
>      the answer different when the notes are of different colors? Explain.
> 2. How many possibilities are there to put in a hat two identical folded notes such that on
>      each of them is a password of length 6? Is the answer different when the notes are of
>      different colors?

My answers are as follows:

> 1. The notes are **identical**, hence we can generate a length 13 password and "split" it in the middle to 6 and 7 length password with no repeats, hence the answer is $\frac{26!}{13!}$.
>      When the notes are **not identical**, we need to multiply the result by 2 as once one colored note has the 6 length pass, and the over the 7 and vice versa. Hence $2(\frac{26!}{13!})$
> 2. The letters can repeat in the password itself and on the other note, but the notes are **identical** hence $(passA, passB) and (passB, passA) \mapsto \left \{ passA, passB \right \}$. Meaning we map 2 to 1, and the answer is $\frac{26^{12}}{2}$. When the colors are **different** we map 1 to 1 hence the answer is $26^{12}$.

We had a debate between us students whether the above are correct, some say the calculations are wrong, some say the colors don't make any difference in the first problem...

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How many possibilities are there to put in a hat $2$ notes such that on one of them is a password of length $6$ and on the other a password of length $7$, such that no letter repeats more than once?

If the notes are identical: $\binom{26}{6+7}\cdot(6+7)!$

If the notes are different: $\binom{26}{6+7}\cdot(6+7)!\cdot2!$

> How many possibilities are there to put in a hat $2$ notes such that on each one of them is a password of length $6$?

If the notes are identical: $26^{6+6}/2!$

If the notes are different: $26^{6+6}$

Comment: In other words, I got the same answers as yours...

Comment: Haha yeah I tried to figure out if these are the same expressions, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Case 1-

We have to pick 13 alphabets total options 26.

Ways = $P(26,7) \times P(19,6) + P(26,6) \times P(20,7)$

In second case -

Number of ways = $P(26,6) \times P(20,6) + P(26,6) \times P(20,6)$

As we have two colours.

Both answers are not same as in one we are picking 13 alphabets and in other 12 alphabets.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, what we are looking to find is how many --possibilities-- are there to create such two note combinations, not the probability. Thanks!

Comment: I have edited my answer.

Comment: When you write c(26,13) you mean 26 choose 13?
Why would we use that here, when actually what we need is (26*25*24*...*14), which is equal to (26!)/(13!)

Comment: Yes sorry its typing error. First I think you are asking about probability that's why I said your first answer is little wrong. But its correct.

Comment: Sorry for that.

Comment: Sorry I think maybe the questions are not clear enough, each question has two cases where first the notes are identical and then they are of different colors.
In the second case, when the notes are identical, if you get a password on one note, you don't need to get it again on the other, did you take that in account?

Comment: Yes I understand both questions now correctly. My answers are according to that.

Comment: In second case we either say this color or that. So we have 2 possibilities thats why I change 4 into 2 in second case.